# Different analyzers for each field

Tags: lucene, lucene.net

How can I enable different analyzers for each field in a document I'm indexing with Lucene?  Example:

```
        RAMDirectory dir = new RAMDirectory();
        IndexWriter iw = new IndexWriter(dir, new StandardAnalyzer(Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_CURRENT), true, IndexWriter.MaxFieldLength.UNLIMITED);
        Document doc = new Document();
        Field field1 = new Field("field1", someText1, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED, Field.TermVector.WITH_POSITIONS_OFFSETS);
        Field field2 = new Field("field2", someText2, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED, Field.TermVector.WITH_POSITIONS_OFFSETS);
        doc.Add(field1);
        doc.Add(field2);
        iw.AddDocument(doc);
        iw.Commit();
```

The analyzer is an argument to the IndexWriter, but I want to use StandardAnalyzer for field1 and SimpleAnalyzer for field2, how can I do that?  The same applies when searching, of course.  The correct analyzer must be applied for each field.

Answer (score 33):

[PerFieldAnalyzerWrapper](http://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs/versions/3_0_0/api/core/org/apache/lucene/analysis/PerFieldAnalyzerWrapper.html) is what you are looking for. The equivalent of this in Lucene.net is [here](http://lucenenet.apache.org/docs/3.0.3/dc/df9/class_lucene_1_1_net_1_1_analysis_1_1_per_field_analyzer_wrapper.html).

Answer (score 10):

```
Map<String, Analyzer> analyzerMap = new HashMap<String, Analyzer>();
analyzerMap.put(fieldone, new IKAnalyzer4PinYin(false, IKAnalyzer4PinYin.PINYIN));
analyzerMap.put(fieldtwo, new IKAnalyzer4PinYin(false, KAnalyzer4PinYin.PINYIN_SHOUZIMU));
PerFieldAnalyzerWrapper wrapper = new PerFieldAnalyzerWrapper(new IKAnalyzer4PinYin(false), analyzerMap);

IndexWriterConfig iwConfig = new IndexWriterConfig(Version.LUCENE_40 , wrapper);
```

Answer (score 4):

Necromancing.
For C#:

```
Lucene.Net.Util.LuceneVersion version = Lucene.Net.Util.LuceneVersion.LUCENE_48;

Dictionary<string, Lucene.Net.Analysis.Analyzer> fieldAnalyzers = 
    new Dictionary<string, Lucene.Net.Analysis.Analyzer>(System.StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

fieldAnalyzers["YourFieldName"] = new Lucene.Net.Analysis.Core.KeywordAnalyzer();

Lucene.Net.Analysis.Miscellaneous.PerFieldAnalyzerWrapper wrapper = 
    new Lucene.Net.Analysis.Miscellaneous.PerFieldAnalyzerWrapper(
        new Lucene.Net.Analysis.Core.KeywordAnalyzer(), fieldAnalyzers);

Lucene.Net.Index.IndexWriterConfig writerConfig = new Lucene.Net.Index.IndexWriterConfig(version, wrapper);
```